# Is there any way to open link URL in My Flutter Application?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, open-with

I received forgot password link in my email and I want to open it in my already installed application. Is there any solution available for the same in flutter?

For reference, I am attaching one screenshot of **Magicbricks**:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to go through the tutorial for this plugin called [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) and link the url from the email that you click on, to your application. There are 2 ways of achieving that using either App/Deep Links (Android) and Universal Links and Custom URL schemes (iOS). Main goal is to have your app being registered to your defined url, so app knows to open once you click on the link.